# Make a table in matrix form to display the values of x and y if y =sin[x] and x takes on the certain values

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, table

[image: Question is:]

Don't understand how to do this, tried plugging in "if" statements but my commands won't go through.

Extremely new to Mathmatica

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your code to your question. Have you tied using the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) function?

Comment: *tried plugging in "if" statement* Plugging into what? *my commands won't go through* What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

xValues = Range[-Pi/2, Pi/2, Pi/4];

(tab = Prepend[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ xValues,
    {TraditionalForm@ HoldForm@x,
     TraditionalForm@ HoldForm[y == Sin[x]]}]) //
 MatrixForm
```

[image]

Placed on a plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {x, y},
 GridLines -> {xValues, Sin /@ xValues},
 Epilog -> {Text[tab, {.95, -0.25}],
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ Rest[tab]}]
```

[image]